# removing a word from a url using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

This is my if statement that will take this example href from the source code:

```
href="/toronto/2013/05/14/the-airborne-toxic-event/4296/"
```

from the source code

```
if ($text=preg_match('/href="([^"]*)"/', $text, $matches))
{
    $output=$matches[1];
    return $output;
}
```

and return

```
/toronto/2013/05/14/the-airborne-toxic-event/4296/
```

I am trying to return that url without either `"/toronto"` or `"/toronto/"` (I'm not sure which one I will need)

If you could show me the regex expression that would do that I would really appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Consider using `str_replace` instead of a regular expression. This use case is simple enough that it's not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
return preg_replace('~^/?toronto/~', '', $output);
```

---

If you're sure that "toronto/" does not appear anywhere else in the string, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
return str_replace('/toronto', '', $output);
```

This assumes there'll always be a leading slash.